# How to modify/change the ember mirage response in my tests file?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

The application uses ember-cli-mirage to mock the data and uses specific endpoint to get the specific response. Mocking data and showing the content to the templates works fine.

Problem: I can't modify the response of this endpoint `GET /foos` in my test file.

`/mirage/config.js`

```
export default function () {
  this.namespace = '/api';

  let foos = {
    foos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo-2',
        description: 'foo description'
      },
    ],
  };

  this.get('/foos', function () {
    return foos;
  });
}
```

`tests/acceptance/foo-test.js`

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL, click, find, findAll } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import setupMirage from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support/setup-mirage';

module('Acceptance | foo', function (hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);

  test('visiting /foo', async function (assert) {
    this.server.get('/foos', () => {
      return new Response(
        200,
        {
          foos: [
            {
              id: 20,
              name: 'foo-3'
            }
          ]
        },
      );
    })

    await visit('/foo');
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/foo');
  });
});
```

Question: How to modify the response of this endpoint `GET /foos` inside my test file? I want my test file to have a different response

Comment: the code looks good at the first glance. Which response do you receive in your test? You might want to enable logging by saying `this.logging = true` in your config file

Answer (score 0):

We just tried your code in a new demo app and I found 2 issues with it.

Firstly you are returning a new `Response` from your server handler which will not work on its own. Without importing anything you have ended up using the [browser's Response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which is not what MirageJS is expecting. To fix this you need to first import `Response` from MirageJS and it will then be using the right object:

```
import { Response } from 'miragejs';
```

The second issue is that you are missing a parameter for the `Response` constructor. It expects 3 parameters: the status code, a headers object, and the data. You have only passed the code and the data, which means that it is considering your data object to be the headers object.

Here is a corrected version of your test code:

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL, click, find, findAll } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';

import setupMirage from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support/setup-mirage';
import { Response } from 'miragejs';

module('Acceptance | foo', function (hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);

  test('visiting /foo', async function (assert) {
    this.server.get('/foos', () => {
      return new Response(
        200,
        {},
        {
          foos: [
            {
              id: 20,
              name: 'foo-3'
            }
          ]
        },
      );
    })

    await visit('/foo');
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/foo');
  });
});
```

You can read more about the MirageJS `Response` object [on the official documentation](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/api/modules/response%7EResponse) and you can catch us answering this question live on the latest episode of [May I Ask a Question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3tzPkkEG64)